# Correct way to escape SVG in `data:` URIs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

Chrome has recently started [blocking URLs with new line and `<` characters](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5735596811091968).

I maintain an application which heavily relies on SVG images within a data URI (`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg>......`). The reason for using the `data:` URI instead of a traditional image or SVG tag is that the SVGs are loaded at run time from an SVG attribute within a larger JSON document.

Will it be possible to use SVGs in `data:` URLs after this change takes place in Chrome 60? What are my alternatives if not?

**UPDATE:** User Álvaro González recommends using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) which indeed makes the deprecation warning go away.

Comment: I'd say to you need `encodeURIComponent()` for the URL itself plus HTML escaping if you're inserting it in HTML, but I haven't really tried.

Comment: Álvaro González: That appears to remove the deprecation warnings. Thank you. If you respond to this question I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A data URI is still a URI so [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) should be the right tool:

> The `encodeURIComponent()` function **encodes a Uniform Resource
>   Identifier (URI)** component by replacing each instance of certain
>   characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing
>   the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape
>   sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

Don't forget to apply it to the image data, not the entire URI.

If the URI is used in CSS that's all you'd need. If you want to inject it in HTML you should also apply HTML encoding on top of that (this time for the complete URI).

Answer (score 1):

`encodeURIComponent()` does the job, but escapes more than it needs to.  Here's a blog post detailing what seems to work best, such as minimizing escape sequences and fixing things like using double-quotes where single-quotes would be more efficient:

https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris

It includes an tool to encode SVG for CSS, which can be used locally or online.  Here's another online tool:

https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

Answer (score 0):

If the URL can have spaces and commas (not in places like `srcset` attribute):

```js
function encodeDataURIText(data) {
  return encodeURI(data).replace(/#|%20/g, s => s == '#' ? '%23' : ' ');
}
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeDataURIText(textData);
```

This avoids escaping characters which can easily appear everywhere, like space  , svg characters like `=',+&/`, css characters like `:;@` as well as `$?`. It escapes `#` so it's not interpreted as URL fragment.
I'm not too sure about `?` though, but at least Firefox is accepting it without issues.

Additionally, if you want to minimize over-escaping, you can make sure:

- the svg uses single quotes instead of double quotes: `attr='value'` (makes a lot of difference in size)
- whitespace (specially tabs and newlines) is collapsed into a single   space

But these depend on context so it can't be done with just a simple regex, therefore, you'd have to do it manually or use some XML (or preferably an SVG) minification library before encoding.

```js
function encodeDataURIText(data) {
  return encodeURI(data).replace(/#|%20/g, s => s == '#' ? '%23' : ' ');
}

const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const url = document.querySelector('input');
const img = document.querySelector('img');

function input() {
  textarea.style.height = '';
  textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
};
textarea.oninput = input;
input();

function load() {
  url.value = img.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeDataURIText(textarea.value);
}
button.onclick = load;
load();
```

```css
textarea { resize: none; }
textarea, img, input { width: 100%; }
img { border: 1px solid black; }
body { padding-right: 8px; }
```

```html
<div><textarea>&lt;svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='100'>
&lt;text style='dominant-baseline:text-before-edge'>lorem ipsum "&amp;amp;#$+,/:;=?@%{}[]()-_.!~*^`|\'&lt;/text>
&lt;/svg></textarea></div>
<div><button>Load</button> <input readonly/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="data:image/svg+xml," /></div>
```