# Trying to set an svg as a background image on a div in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am importing the SVG in my component like -

```
import Confetti from './Confetti.svg';

type ConfettiWrapperProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ConfettiWrapper = (props: ConfettiWrapperProps) => {
  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${Confetti})`,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Webpack config -

```
{
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
          },
},
```

For some reason, I can't see the `background-image` attribute on my div at all.

Passing in `Confetti` as `src` in an `img` tag works. I am clueless here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the url:

`encodeURIComponent()`

[Correct way to escape SVG in `data:` URIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570636/correct-way-to-escape-svg-in-data-uris)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Just tried this out and can confirm this doesn't work.

Comment: That's how I do it in my app, works great. That said, I've done a search and found another SO post that should be of help. (Added to answer)